# Pythonic way of getting a value from a list

Tags: python, string, list, parsing, split

EDIT: Added part (b) of the question

I have a long string that is like this:

```
"a=x b=x c=x..."
```

a,b,c... are the same all the time, while the x's differ. What I want is to get lets say b=x but only if x matches a specific string.

So far, I pass the string to a list and I split the values by spaces, like this:

```
['a=x', 'b=x', 'c=x'...]
```

a) What is the most pythonic way of getting b=x only when x="something_I_want"? (solved)

b) What is the way to get the x for given b? In other words, I want to get what is equal to my known value b.

A solution for (b) is:

```
k = "PROTO="
keep = [ele for ele in x.split() if ele.startswith(k)]
print str(keep[0]).split('=')[1]
```

Something similar to what @Padraic Cunningham suggested below in the answers. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: what output do you actually want if x is equal to something you want?

Comment: Basically, x value *should* be a specific value, but sometimes it is not. I want to get the whole string if the x value equals with something I want.

Comment: then all you need is str.endswith

Comment: I edited my answer, you can so it all the the comprehension or use a generator expression with next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter only based on the value of `x`, you can use a single list comprehension with `str.endswith`:

```
keep = [ele for ele in s.split() if ele.endswith("=whatever") ]
```

Using your test string:

```
x = "Jun 30 13:07:51 xxxx kernel: 15702368.296557 UFW BLOCK IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=so:me:mac SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=47632 PROTO=TCP SPT=58875 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CK FIN URGP=0"
k = "=TCP"
keep = [ele for ele in x.split() if ele.endswith(k)]
['PROTO=TCP']
```

Some timings show just using str.endswith and split is  most efficient:

```
In [49]: timeit [ele for ele in x.split() if ele.endswith(k)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.81 µs per loop

In [50]: timeit re.findall(r"\b[^= ]*="+re.escape(k)+r"\b",x)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.5 µs per loop

In [51]: [ele for ele in x.split() if ele.endswith(k)]
Out[51]: ['PROTO=TCP']

In [52]: re.findall(r"\b[^= ]*="+re.escape(k)+r"\b",x)
Out[52]: ['PROTO=TCP']
```

If you just want the first match or if there is ever only one match:

```
k = "PROTO="

keep = (ele.split("=")[1] for ele in x.split() if ele.startswith(k))
print(next(keep,""))

TCP
```

Or split after:

```
k = "PROTO="
keep = (ele for ele in x.split() if ele.startswith(k))
print(next(keep,"").split("=")[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
>>> s = 'a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4'
>>> parsed = [x.split('=') for x in s.split()]
>>> whatineed = [k for k, v in parsed if v == '2']
>>> whatineed
['b']
```

If all values (`x`s) are different, and you need to do a lot of retrieval, you can convert the string into a `value->key` dict:

```
>>> p = dict(reversed(x.split('=')) for x in s.split())
>>> p
{'1': 'a', '3': 'c', '2': 'b', '4': 'd'}
>>> p['2']
'b'
```

As for the "pythonic" bit, when you have to deal with structured data in a string form, it's cleaner (and hence "more pythonic") to convert this string to an actual structure (list, dict) first, and then retrieve the data you need. Extracting *data* with *string* functions is cumbersome and unreliable in most cases.

Comment: making `dict` may not work as `s = 'a=1 b=2 c=2 d=4'`

Comment: @ferhatelmas: that's why I said: "if all values are different..."

Comment: sorry hadn't read surrounding text carefully and only checked code. still getting used to rushing for an answer ;)

Comment: @georg I am getting error: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack".

Comment: For safety split only once, just in case values contain `=`.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is through `re`.

```
import re
x = "a=x b=i_want_this c=x.. b=sdf b=wer."
k="i_want_this"
print re.findall(r"\bb="+re.escape(k)+r"\b",x)
```

Comment: Don't forget to re.escape `k`.

Comment: I am getting an empty list.

Comment: @vks Normally, I saved it in a .py file and then ran it in terminal. I just replaced variable x and of the value of k. What I get is just [ ].

Comment: @vks  x = "Jun 30 13:07:51 xxxx kernel: 15702368.296557 UFW BLOCK IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=so:me:mac SRC=xx.xx.xx.xx DST=xx.xx.xx.xx LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=55 ID=47632 PROTO=TCP SPT=58875 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 CK FIN URGP=0"

k = "TCP"

Comment: @antonis_man use `print re.findall(r"\b[^= ]*="+re.escape(k)+r"\b",x)`

Comment: @vks Yes, I should have changed the regex criteria, since there are more patterns in the string than a=x b=x... Thanks, it worked.

Comment: There is no need for a regex at all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most 'pythonic' way to solve the problem, but i think it's a safe solution :)..

```
def getValueOfString(str, x):
   dict = {}
   for i in s.split():
     item = i.split("=")
     if dict.has_key(item[1]):
       dict[item[1]].append(item[0])
     else:
       dict[item[1]] = [item[0]]
   return dict[x] if dict.has_key(x) else []
```